# How to detect user touch with phonegap using JS

Tags: javascript, android, touch, cordova

I am using phonegap to build android apps.

I would like to detect the touch event from a user so I can pop-up an alert. However, how do I call the ontouch event from javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Below is an example that shows `touchstart` and `touchend`. It demonstrates two different ways to attach touch events: element attributes or JavaScript's `addEventListener`.

Since it is listening for touch events, the events will not fire on a desktop browser (which supports mouse events). To test the page, you can open it a Android or iOS simulator.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" />
    <style type="text/css">
      a {
        color:black;
        display:block;
        margin:10px 0px;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onload() {
        document.getElementById('touchstart').addEventListener('touchstart', hello, false);
        document.getElementById('touchend').addEventListener('touchend', bye, false);
      }

      function hello() {
        alert('hello');
      }

      function bye() {
        alert('bye');
      }
    </script>

    <title>Touch Example</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="onload();">
    <h1>Touch</h1>
    <a href="#" ontouchstart="hello();return false;">Attribute: ontouchstart</a>
    <a href="#" ontouchend="bye();return false;">Attribute: ontouchend</a>
    <a href="#" id="touchstart">addEventListener: touchstart</a>
    <a href="#" id="touchend">addEventListener: touchend</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mwbrroks I have tried out and it works well with a link/button. However i was wondering if it could work on a blank screen without any link or button.. meaning as long user touch anywhere on the screen it would display a popup. isit possible? :) thanks

Comment: Do a window.addEventListener(etc)

Comment: Though fully not solved but your answer gave me some direction to initiate. But now there is one more problem and that is that the keyboard appears and when I touch its keys, it gets disappear suddenly. How can I resolve this?

Comment: get jquery mobile for access to different touch events from jquery